# get user who not login from last 30 days in sql asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to try get record's who not logging from last 30 days.
I have try and I also got the records but,
that records display from the database who logging ed before 30 days.
But I want to show, who's not logging from last 30 days from current date, which I can disable them.

I try below query on sql

```
select distinct CmsUserLogTime.UserId  
from CmsUserLogTime 
right join CmsUser on CmsUserLogTime.UserId = CmsUser.Id
where CmsUserLogTime.LoginLogoutTime <= DateAdd(Day, -30, GetDate()) 
order by 1 asc
```

I just want to compare from current date to last 30 days, which I can get the records.

Thanks.

Comment: mysql <> sql server.

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself in the question.  Do you want users who have not had login/logout activity for 30 days or more, or do you want something else?

Comment: Be careful....ordering by ordinal position has a lot of challenges with it. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Answer (score 3):

Using `NOT IN`

```
select 
    CmsUserLogTime.UserId  
from CmsUserLogTime 
inner join CmsUser on CmsUserLogTime.UserId = CmsUser.Id
where CmsUserLogTime.UserId in (select UserID from CmsUserLogTime group by UserID having max(LoginLogoutTime) <= dateadd(day,-30,getdate()))
```

Note, since you aren't returning columns from the `CmsUser` table, I don't see the need to `JOIN` to it, but left it in in case you actually do want columns from that table.

Comment: You have very strong powers of comprehension +1.

Comment: HAHA thank's @TimBiegeleisen, it's from reading answers from you and other gurus

Comment: Thank you very much for spend your valuable time for me @scsimon It's working for me again thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Use DATEADD in your WHERE clause:

...

```
WHERE CmsUserLogTime.LoginLogoutTime < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

You can also use abbreviation d or dd instead of day.

Comment: This would also return users that have logged in, say, today which i don't think is intended. Also, I wouldn't use shorthand dates. Check out this blog: https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: Thanks Mr. for your blog